# (Algorithm | NetLogo) How can I create and fill a polygon based on coordinate input?

Tags: math, polygon, netlogo

I started working with NetLogo recently. I wanted to create different kinds of terrain in NetLogo. I thought of polygons to do the job. The basic idea was to input a list with coordinates and based on that list the program should go through the list and create a polygon.

In NetLogo I need to address every patch - Part on the coordinate system like (1|4) or (-5|3) - and tell it to change his attributes/variables.

Now I did some research on how to achieve that goal but I'm not that good in maths and I couldn't figure out a way to actually do this.

Maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

While pondering a nice way to implement a polygon from a list,  I'd suggest a much easier solution which is to make a pretty picture of the terrain you like in a paint program and then import it using "import-pcolors filename".

The nice thing is that most paint programs understand paint-bucket functionality and flood-filling an area with a color or even a texture.  I'm scratching my head trying to think how NetLogo would recognize that a point was inside versus outside an arbitrary polygon!   I suspect you'd have to recreate the flood-filling algorithm which, having done it, is not easy or pretty.   ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill  but the special cases and stack overflows and other such things make it hard to generalize safely. )

Comment: Yeah, I came across the flood filling algorithm. I would also need to have a safe way to create the polygon shape around the actual polygon without interfering with shapes and colors that might already have been used.

Why I wanted to create the polygon myself with points - I could let it generate randomly. But if I could use the procedure mentioned above, maybe I could create a random terrain picture elsewhere and fetch it via one of the request extensions.